# MVC - Where does extra data generated just for the UI get stored?

Tags: silverlight, model-view-controller

We are building a Silverlight app and using PureMVC but the technology and framework probably aren't that important to this question.

We have a view that contains a grid and that grid is bound to a model.  However, we have additional columns of data that we would like to display for the user but the data is derived and not stored in the model.

Where is the best place within MVC to handle this?

Any help or suggestions would greatly be appreciated!

Thanks a lot,

Bobby

Comment: By derived, do you mean calculated from the other columns?

Answer (score 1):

Add properties to your model object for the additional columns then wire up the logic behind them in their property gets and bind them to the grid as additional columns.

Comment: Another option is to abstract the model and use the Model, View, ViewModel approach where your View is the standard Silverlight/ASP.NET unaware business tier and your ViewModel is more aware of how to bring together the components for the purpose of displaying and managing data between the client and middle tier.

Answer (score 0):

From a 'patterns' approach, do not change your model (unless your model already is purposed as a ViewModel. Implement a specific view model in this case. A view model should have view logic (additional columns, code specific to the model layout, etc) a plain model should not.